# Networking - Routing Between VPN and LAN

Tags: networking, routing

I have two computers connected via a VPN with application netovernet and when trying to access `192.168.1.10` from Computer 1, it doesn't succeed, even though I've activate routing in both computers via:

```
route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.2
```

- **VPN Server:** `88.198.37.3`
- **Computer 1:** 
   NIC: `192.168.43.182` 
   VPN: `192.168.99.1`
- **Computer 2:** 
   NIC1: `192.168.43.100` 
   VPN: `192.168.99.2` 
   NIC2: `192.168.1.10`
- **Computer 3:** `192.168.1.20`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps draw a simple diagram of what you are connecting.

Here is a simple diagram of a basic connection.

You have your VPN server software on a PC.

That external address is 88.198.37.3 .

Your local server address is 192.168.43.x  .

Your local subnet mask is 255.255.255.0  .

If you want more computers here, your VPN server software needs to handle that.

The VPN's server points to a remote group as a dynamic IP and an identifier such as a FQDN email address. This is a function of the client software.

Try to make a diagram that roughly matches this one and that will help you sort out your needs.

I do this here but I use a Hardware VPN router in my home office so I can attach multiple computers if I need to.

[image]